# When defining module in RequireJS, what's the difference between returning an object VS returning an init() function?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a JS module to store some configuration objects. I'm using it like enums in c#.

When requiring it in another module, what's the difference between the following 2 implementations?

### 1.

Types.js

```
define([], function(){
    var types = {
        typeA: "Type A",
        typeB: "Type B",
        typeC: "Type C"
    };
    return {types: types};
});
```

Usage

```
define(["Types.js"], function(types){
    var types = types;
    ...
});
```

### 2.

Types.js

```
define([], function(){
    var init = function(){
        var types = {
            typeA: "Type A",
            typeB: "Type B",
            typeC: "Type C"
        };
        return {types: types};
    };      
    return {init: init};
});
```

Usage

```
define(["Types.js"], function(types){
    var types = types.init();
    ...
});
```

---

Is there any differences between those 2 implementations? Or are they just the same?

Comment: One returns a function, another returns an object.

Comment: Imagine if creating the object requires a lot of calculations - Implementation 2 lets you defer those calculations until the object is needed. Also, though your example doesn't do so, in a general sense Implementation 2 gives you the option of passing parameters to the `init()` function.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, I have params to pass to ```init()```, just omitted. Thank you for your answer, helped a lot!

Comment: Option one is going to return a singleton.  Option 2 is returning a function that everytime is called is going to return a new object.  So there really doing different things, and for configs I'd go option 1.

Answer (score 0):

The second implementation is more like OOP-style, because you can make several instances of the class Types: types = new Types(someParams); and use it fields and methods. But the first implementation only returns object.